# ActionLinkButton BoostrapMVC - Passando valores para controller. "MVC - C#"

Tags: c#

Estou tentando criar um botão com boostrap mvc, que quando for clicado ira abrir uma nova aba com os dados que eu quero, mas para isso preciso passar um Id para o meu controller, alguem poderia me ajudar, pois não consigo passar esse id usando ActionLinkButton, teria outra forma de fazer???

Algum exemplo em bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que faço algo parecido.

No HTML:

```
<button href="#@Id" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btConfirmar">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
```

No Jquery:

```
$(".btConfirmar").on("click", function () {
    idAprov = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    // aqui voce pode chamar sua tela passando o ID 
}
```